# Show the SQL generated by Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to get the SQL issued by Flask-SQLAlchemy queries.  In Django, I can print the `query` attribute to get SQL.  How can I get something similar in Flask?

```
# django
>>> queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
>>> print queryset.query
SELECT "myapp_mymodel"."id", ... FROM "myapp_mymodel"
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy records debugging information about all queries during a request.  You can get the information with [`get_debug_queries()`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.0/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.get_debug_queries).  [Flask-Debugtoolbar](https://flask-debugtoolbar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/panels.html#sqlalchemy), for example, uses this to offer a debug panel with query timing information on each page render.

`get_debug_queries()` returns a list of queries in the order they were performed.

```
>>> from my_app import User
>>> from flask_sqlalchemy import get_debug_queries
>>> User.query.filter_by(display_name='davidism').all()
>>> info = get_debug_queries()[0]
>>> print(info.statement, info.parameters, info.duration, sep='\n')
SELECT "user".id AS user_id, se_user.id AS se_user_id, se_user.display_name AS se_user_display_name, se_user.profile_image AS se_user_profile_image, se_user.profile_link AS se_user_profile_link, se_user.reputation AS se_user_reputation, "user".superuser AS user_superuser \nFROM se_user JOIN "user" ON se_user.id = "user".id \nWHERE se_user.display_name = %(display_name_1)s
{'display_name_1': 'davidism'}
0.0016849040985107422
```

Queries are recorded if `SQLALCHEMY_RECORD_QUERIES` is set to `True`.  This should be disabled when not needed for performance reasons.

---

Just calling `str(query)` does not show exactly what is sent to the database, as the final render is up to the lower-level database driver.  SQLAlchemy has only the parameterized string and unescaped parameters.  See [the SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined) for a very detailed explanation of why.  Usually it's good enough, but it's good to be aware that it's not the final query.

Answer (score 14):

To print the generated SQL for all the queries, set the configuration `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO=True`.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
```

http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/config/

Answer (score 12):

I have found answer. I just invoke `str` and then get the sql.

```
>>> str(User.query.filter_by(role_id=user_role))
'SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.username AS users_username, users.role_id AS
 users_role_id \nFROM users \nWHERE users.role_id = :role_id_1'
```

Comment: `print` is a bit better, as it actually wraps instead of outputting "\n" `str(User.query.filter_by(role_id=user_role))`